# Access to model element by it's DB column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have an settings table in my laravel project, which has 4 fields:

- id
- field_name
- field_code (unique)
- value

(For example: I store email of organization like: `field-name=Email`, `field_code=email`, `value=info@domain.com`)

I've shared all model objects to view via ServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    $settings = Setting::all();

    View::share('details', $settings);
}
```

How can I access elements in blade template using `field_code` column?

```
{{ $details['email']->name }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`firstWhere`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-first-where).

`$details->firstWhere('field_code', 'email')->name`